# Store null or blanks in an integer type column in PostgreSQL 11

Tags: python, postgresql

I am inserting values in a PostgreSQL 11.0 table through my python script. There is a column type 'integer'. I would like to fill null if the column has no value.

```
drop table if exists tbl;
create table tbl (
        id character varying,
        enr_val integer,
        enr_type character varying
    )
```

```
        if re.match('^\d+ \[.*\]', enr):
            enr_val = re.search(r"(.*) \[.*", enr).group(1)
            enr_type = re.search(r".* \[(.*)\]", enr).group(1)
        elif re.match('\d+$', enr):
            enr_val = re.search(r"(.*)", enr).group(1)
            enr_type = 'null'
        else:
            enr_val = 'null'
            enr_type = 'null'
```

How can I insert null when the else condition is true?

Answer (score 0):

Python `None` will produce a `Null` value in the DB

```
if re.match('^\d+ \[.*\]', enr):
    enr_val = re.search(r"(.*) \[.*", enr).group(1)
    enr_type = re.search(r".* \[(.*)\]", enr).group(1)
elif re.match('\d+$', enr):
    enr_val = re.search(r"(.*)", enr).group(1)
    enr_type = None
else:
    enr_val = None
    enr_type = None
```